# Jquery Toggle Cookies not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, toggle

So I made my jquery toggle cookie script, but its not working. Like, when I click on the trigger, nothing happens.

Basically, what this code does is if the content is hidden, we add a cookie to remember that state that it is hidden. And when the user toggles again, we will delete that cookie. Also, how can I keep the state of the chevrons as well through cookies?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
if ($.cookie('t4hidden')) {
    $('#top4hide').hide();
}
$("#top4trigger").click(function () {
    $("i",this).toggleClass("fa fa-chevron-up fa fa-chevron-down")
    $("#top4hide").toggle("blind");
});
$("#top4trigger").click(function() {
    if ($("#top4hide").is(":hidden")) {
    $.cookie("t4hidden", "foo");
} else {
    $.removeCookie("t4hidden");
}
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P2dy8/

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate the problem, please? It'll help people debug it.

Comment: Here ya go :) http://jsfiddle.net/P2dy8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is timing. You have two click callbacks in your code: one to toggle the display of the element, and one to set the cookie. You can't control which one gets run first, but even if you could that wouldn't help. The first callback hides the element with animation, so when the second callback fires the element's still visible. Your check for `$('#top4hide").is(":hidden")` always returns false, because regardless of when it runs - first or second - it's still visible at the time.

Fortunately, [you can pass a second parameter to jQuery's `toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - a function that runs when animation is complete. By checking the element's visibility after the animation, we can set the cookie value correctly. I've posted some [working code over on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BymY/), as well as below; it also toggles your chevron when hiding the div on pageload if the cookie is set. (You'll need the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/) loaded to get `$.cookie()` and `$.removeCookie()`.)

```
$(function() { // $() is an alternative syntax for $(document).ready()
    if ($.cookie('t4hidden')) { // Update page if cookie is set
        $('#top4hide').hide();
        $('#top4trigger i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down');
    }

    $("#top4trigger").click(function() { // Click handler for link
        $("i", this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-up fa-chevron-down")
        $("#top4hide").toggle("blind", function () { // Set/delete cookie after animation complete
            if ($("#top4hide").is(":hidden")) {
                $.cookie("t4hidden", "foo");
            } else {
                $.removeCookie("t4hidden");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Its not working. I am getting this error :/ Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Did you load the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/)? You need that included in your page to get a `$.cookie` and `$.removeCookie` function.

Comment: Nope it wasn't loaded, that was the reason why haha!